# Paypal IPN Confirmation Screen immediately after redirect without reload

Tags: php, paypal

I made a script for IPN which works great but how can i immediately notify the user?

I mean paypal redirects the customer to a custom-page i can define, simultanously my ipn.php checked the status,

BUT how can i **immediately** tell the customer on this custom-page that it was successful or not.

this custom-page does somehow has to know that this is the customer-xyz which made the ipn-verified!!! payment xyz, but how? i think also this custom-page redirect should wait the 5 seconds because php does only process files/request on-loads... so after 5 seconds the ipnscript surely did complete.

Sorry if this question is too newby but i dont know how to notify the customer about the (ipn-verified!!!) payment-status immediately.

How do you do this?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a customer is redirected to your "return" page, you can use PDT (which is much the same process as IPN) to determine which transaction has completed.

You need to use IPN to action the purchase (as the user could close their web browser before returning to your website, and thus never see the return page). You can then use PDT to confirm the transaction and thank the user for their purchase, give them access to anything that they can then download, display their package tracking details, or whatever.

Comment: omg thanks. i found this page and assume thats all to know about PDT, yes?
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/xcl/rec/pdt-techview-outside

So can i pretty much copy/paste the first part of my ipn-script (getting the token and replaying back to receive TRUE|FALSE) and then alter the code to show the user live-action like download, login-credentials, etc.?

Comment: here are codesamples, unfortunately not very good ones.

just as info for others:
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/xcl/rec/pdt-code-outside

Comment: thx, it works perfectly. Info and explanation was great. unfortunately i dont have any point to vote yet